# how to restart horizontal progressbar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-handler

I've a horizontal progressbar which shows progress from 0 to 100. What I want is to restart the progressbar again from 0 when it reaches 100. I'll be showing this in a Fragmentdialog. For now I'm checking it in activity itself. How to do that?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private Button startbtn, stopbtn;
    ProgressBar pb;
    private TextView progressTxt;

    int progressBarValue = 0;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        show = new CShowProgress(MainActivity.this);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        startbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
        stopbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopbtn);
        pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progressTxt);

        startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myprogress(true);
            }
        });

        stopbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myprogress(false);
            }
        });
    }

    private void myprogress(final Boolean isStart){
        handler = new Handler()
        {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
            {
                if(isStart && progressBarValue<100)
                {
                    progressBarValue+=1;
                    pb.setProgress(progressBarValue);
                    progressTxt.setText(String.valueOf(progressBarValue));

                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
                }

            }
        };

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this chunk of code will work for your use case:

```
private void myprogress(final Boolean isStart) {
  handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      if (isStart && progressBarValue < 100) {
          ...
      } else if (isStart) {
        // progressBarValue is equal to 100
        // make it zero and do the same thing again
        progressBarValue = 0;
        progressBarValue += 1;
        pb.setProgress(progressBarValue);
        progressTxt.setText(String.valueOf(progressBarValue));

        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
      }
    }
  };

  handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use a counter mechanizm (run a delayed handler, timer, thread or something else)to check current progress periodically.

```
 (progressTxt.getProgress == 100)
```

will do the trick.

Another way is using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209642/android-progress-bar-listener).